# Order relation proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Consider the set $A = \{1, 2, 3\}$, and set $B = A × A$. In the set $B$, consider then the relationship $C$ defined by placing

$(a, b) C (c, d)\iff a ≤ c$ and $b | d$

where $≤$ and $|$ denote respectively the usual arrangement and that of the division in $\mathbb{N}$.

• Prove that $C$ is an order relationship in $B$

Can someone explain me how to solve this exercise? Thanks.

Comment: Why did you delete the previous version instead of editing it?  The comment somebody else gave about looking up the definitions of total order and partial order was a good one.

Answer (score 1):

$B$ consists of $9$ ordered pairs.  To have a partial order you just need that if $e,f,g$ are ordered pairs in $B$, if $eCf, fCg$ then $eCg$ and that if $eCf, fCe$ then $e=f$.  I suggest you find some pairs $eCf$ to get a feel for how this relation works.  That may help proving that it is a partial order.  It is not a total order because $(2,2)$ and $(3,3)$ are not comparable-neither is greater than the other.

Comment: Can you write all the passages, I didn't understand well.

Comment: Can you find two different pairs $e,f$ so that $eCf?$  Do you understand the relation?  Do you know what a partial order is?